# Add vector retrieval tool to Langchain load_tools()

Tags: python-3.x, langchain

I'm building a multi tool agent using Llama2-7b-chat autoGPTQ model. Please I want to add these tools

```
llm_math = LLMMathChain(llm=llm, verbose=False)
math_tool = Tool(
    name='Calculator',
    func=llm_math.run,
    description='Useful for when you need to answer questions about math.'
)


rag_tool2=Tool(name='Knowledge Base', func = lambda query: qa2({"question": query}), description = (
        'use this tool when answering general knowledge queries to get '
        'more information about the topic'
    ) )
rag_tool=Tool(
        name="Document QA System",
        func=qa.run,
     return_direct=True,
        description="useful for when you need to answer questions about content, files, documents. Input should be a fully formed question.",
    )
```

to my agent tools here:

```
tools=load_tools(["llm-math"],llm=llm)
```